# Lack of motivation-Changing PhD

Tags: phd, motivation, quitting

I know there are different posts about changing PhD, but with such an important decision I would like to ask the same question but including the details of my personal situation.

I am in the first year of my PhD (now starting the 8th month). I did my masters in my home country, Spain, where I did research in computational protein dynamics although my background is about computational chemistry at atomistic level (Quantum Mechanics). I really enjoyed my masters, but I decided to look for a PhD position in quantum chemistry again. I got this position in Stockholm University. I though I would enjoy it, but after 7 months I am not enjoying at all, I do not trust my own research and my interests are moving far from this field. The thing that my group is the only computational group of the whole department is also a big point, because all other groups are experimental and this make me feel quite isolated.

I already had a talk with my boss, where I expressed all my concerns and where we agreed to look for new things. He was really open-minded and comprehensive, and I will try my best for the next months to see if the change fits me. However, my apathy feeling is still present and I think I should start considering the possibility of changing PhD. Do you think I must change only considering this personal feelings? In the past I was really passionate in science, but this feeling of apathy is keeling me. I want to make clear that there is not any problem with my boss or my group mates (all of them are really fantastic), just with myself and my motivation.

Any opinion and advise is welcome